# Count aggregation on jsonb field using Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql

Imagine a model in **Django** like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
        data = JSONField()
        .
        .
        .
```

The data is stored like this: `{'1':'value1', '2':'value2', '3':'value3', ...}`. The data keys are `['1', '2', '3', ...]`.

The query aim is to **count the number of MyModels which have ids like '1' or '2' in data keys**.
The **PostgreSql** query is like:

```
SELECT jsonb_object_keys(data) AS keys, COUNT(*) AS number FROM MyModel WHERE data ?| array['1','2'] GROUP BY keys
```

The result is:

```
keys | number
-----+-------
 '1' |  150
 '2' |  300
```

This means there are 150 MyModels that have '1' in their data keys and 300 MyModels with '2' in data keys.

Now the question is **how to implement the query with Django?**

Please consider that I know ways with `MyModels.objects.raw()` or `connection.cursor()` but **I'm looking for a solution with Django ORM**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the results that have `1` try this: (and similarly for `2`)

```
key1_objects = Mymodel.objects.filter(data__has_key='1')
```

Try this to get the results that include `1` and exclude `2`

```
key1_objects= Mymodel.objects.filter(data__has_key='1',data__2__isnull=True)
```

and, this to get the result that include `2` and exclude `1`

```
key2_objects= Mymodel.objects.filter(data__has_key='2',data__1__isnull=True)
```

Of course the two latter results don't include objects have both `1` and `2`

If you are sure that `1` and `2` are independent and there is no intersection. It doesn't need to exclude the other key, as selecting `1` implies excluding `2`

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using connection.cursor() but I'm looking for a solution with Django ORM. Not with .raw() or connection.cursor().

Comment: try this `MyModel.objects.filter(Q(data__has_key='1') | Q(data__has_key='2'))` with `Q objects`

Comment: This is not good for counting objects having different tags separately. Consider the result table I wrote in question.

Comment: You mean you want the result that include 1 and exclude 2 ? your question asks about having 1 or 2

Comment: Yes I need the result of 1 and 2 seperately. They may be unrelated to each other.